# Box-shadow: inset property css

Tags: css, box-shadow

I saw this code on Codepen. It is part of a larger project. My question is why is there two sets of "inset" properties for box-shadow? Does both of them have the same function? Can I delete one of them?  Thanks in advance for the help!!

Link to the original projects: http://codepen.io/tholman/pen/BLeJs

```
.trapdoor {

position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -25px;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transition: background 400ms ease-in-out;
box-shadow: inset -7px 0px 12px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 7px 0px 12px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Delete one, see the difference; reinstate and then delete the other, see the difference. Of course you *can* delete one, but first why not see if you *should* or if you *want* to? What, exactly, is the question you want us to answer for you?

Comment: It looks like there is an inset shadow for the left of the element and one for the right.

Answer (score 3):

answer: 
Basically: "The box-shadow property describes one or more shadow effects as a comma-separated list."
In your code example the first inset is the right side and the second is the left, the shadow is difficult to see because the opacity is set to 0.3 I have include a sample code showing the same insets but colored blue and red.

This website has some good information on the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) style:

Here is a CodePen showing variations of the class:
http://codepen.io/ctwoodwa/pen/PZwOwQ

```css
.trapdoor {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 25%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -25px;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transition: background 400ms ease-in-out;
box-shadow: inset -7px 0px 12px -8px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1), inset 7px 0px 12px -8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
.trapdoor2 {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -25px;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transition: background 400ms ease-in-out;
box-shadow: inset -7px 0px 12px -8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapdoor">First inset is blue</div>
<div class="trapdoor2">Second is red</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two `inset` styles declared to cover both sides of the element, providing the correct contrast desired, giving the 3d/perspective effect.
declaring them both and offsetting them equally is something we observe naturally on objects, although the observations are not always as congruent.
you can delete one if you like, but you'll notice when you do that your element now has intricate shadow style on only one of its sides...if that is desired, then you'll be happy.
"do both of them have the same function"
of course, they're the same css property declaration; only difference is the x-axis offset value following the inset shadow declarations. in this case, one is -7 pixels left, while the other is 7 pixels right.